# What is the differene between sockets & proxy passing between nginx and uwsgi?

Tags: javascript, html, nginx

I have a simple project that is set up  with flask, uwsgi, and nginx. The backend acts only as an API serving json, with all the rendering happening on the client side.

I usually configure Nginx as follows:

*My setup (with simple proxy passing):*

```
server{
    listen 80;

    location / {
        default_type "text/html";
        alias /home/user/Project/frontend/;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header Connection "keep-alive";

    }
}
```

Which I imagine is functioning in this manner:

```
User -------> Nginx (frontend) ---(proxy pass via Nginx)---> Uwsgi (backend)
```

However, recently I came across a setup that uses sockets
*Alternative setup (with unix sockets):*

```
server{
    listen 80;

    location / {
        default_type "text/html";
        alias /home/mahmoud/Documents/Projects/Research/Countries/frontend/;
    }

    location /api/ {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user/Project/backend/app.sock;
    }
}
```

The referenced uwsgi_params file is found [here](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/uwsgi_params).

So my questions is:
**What is the advantage/disadvantage of using the second approach? Is it a matter of performance? If yes, why does it perform faster/slower and are there other aspects to it?**

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34567532/1606432

Comment: I believe uwsgi is faster (but not by a lot) mainly because in uwsgi, binary length bytes are already known.. So as you can see, minimal improvement. But uwsgi protocol is there, so might aswel use it.

Answer (score 0):

with unix socket your FastCgi will application will be secure. you can apply permissions on sockets and it will not be accessible remotely.